# How to Set an NSInteger __block variable to comboboxFilter.indexOfSelectedItem inside of dispatch_async

Tags: objective-c, codeblocks, osx-mavericks, dispatch-async

I have been trying to set an NSInteger block variable to the value of a combobox's selected index inside a thread.  The variable is always zero outside of the dispatch_async even though it has been set inside the dispatch_async.

When I NSLog the value of the variable "comboboxFilterSelectedIndex" from within the dispatch_async it holds the correct index value, however it looses the value when returning the DoSearch thread.

Needless to say I am not proficient at objective c and could sure use some help.

Thank you

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    doSearch(directoryURL, words, self->tableContents, self.tableViewOutlet, self.checkboxLookInPathOutlet, self.checkboxContainsAllWordsOutlet, self.checkboxContainsWholeWordsOutlet, self.comboboxFilterOutlet, self.labelHitCountOutlet, self.imageViewThumbnailOutlet, self.labelFilesCountOutlet, self.textViewMetadataOutlet, self.labelElapsedTimeOutlet);
    //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){


    // Next 2 must be used in main thread only
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.buttonSearchOutlet.enabled = true;
        self.buttonSearchOutlet.title = @"Search";
    });
    return;

    //});
});


void doSearch(NSURL *searchPathURL, NSArray *searchWords, 
    NSMutableArray *tableContents, NSTableView *tableView, NSButton 
    *checkboxLookInPath, NSButton *checkboxContainsAllWords, NSButton 
   *checkboxContainsWholeWords, NSComboBox *comboboxFilter, 
    NSTextField *labelHitCount, NSImageView * imageViewThumbnail, 
    NSTextField *labelFilesCount, NSTextView *textViewMetadata, 
    NSTextField *labelElapsedTime){

    For ...{

        //__block NSInteger comboboxFilterSelectedIndex = All;
        __block NSInteger comboboxFilterSelectedIndex = 0;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"------------>%lu", comboboxFilter.indexOfSelectedItem); // Value is correct
            comboboxFilterSelectedIndex = comboboxFilter.indexOfSelectedItem;
            NSLog(@"------------>%lu", comboboxFilterSelectedIndex); // Value is correct
        });

        NSLog(@"------------>%lu", comboboxFilterSelectedIndex); //Value is Always = 0

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is a `}` missing between the `NSLog`s?

Comment: `dispatch_async`: "Submits a block for asynchronous execution on a dispatch queue and **returns immediately**." See [dispatch_sync](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452870-dispatch_sync?language=occ)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the missing }.  This is just a partial code snip.  I have already looked at the dispatch_aync but it doesn't show how to transfer/copy a UI object value in this case the selected index value of the combo to a variable in the parent thread.

Comment: You right this duplicate, however I didn't see a solution to the problem given.  I guess at this point I don't have a clue as to how to retrieve the value synchronously without a cross-thread exception.  I am more familiar with Visual C#  where I would create a delegate and use the invoke method of the combo box.  Is there an equivalent to "delegate and invoke" in objective c that you could point me to or something to search for?

Comment: Usually you get the values from the controls and then start a background search with these values.